# Python "requests" vs "urllib3" to AWS API Gateway

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am writing a python program that calls AWS API Gateway to reach dynamoDB.

And it all works fine when I use python "requests":
r = requests.post("https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/log-entries",
data={'logbookTimestamp': timestamp, 'Name': "Fred"})

Now in order to run this as a lambda function, I want to use "urllib3" instead of "requests"
because urllib3 is included by default in lambda's python. So now I am trying to do the same with urllib3 but can't get it to work. I've read the urllib3 user guide here (https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#json) and it says I need to encode the JSON data before sending it so I've done this:

```
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
fields = {'logbookTimestamp': timestamp, 'Name': "Fred"}
encoded_fields = json.dumps(fields).encode('utf-8')
link = "https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/log-entries"
r = http.request('POST',
                 link,
                 body=encoded_fields,
                 headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
                 )
```

When I look at the output of both in CloudWatch I see that the data are formatted differently.

With requests:
(c084a37e-43d8-464a-9dcf-e40c28922ece) Method request body before transformations: logbookTimestamp=2020%3A12%3A15%3A20%3A11%3A02&Name=Fred

With urllib3:
(9b8d84e9-2403-462c-b25f-945a927d1e66) Method request body before transformations:
{
"logbookTimestamp": "2020:12:15:21:31:21",
"Name": "Fred"
}

and returns the following:
(9b8d84e9-2403-462c-b25f-945a927d1e66) Endpoint response body before transformations:
{
"statusCode": 500,
"headers": {
"Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8",
"Content-Length": "290"
},
"body": "\n500 Internal Server Error\n

## Internal Server Error

\n

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

\n"
}
(9b8d84e9-2403-462c-b25f-945a927d1e66) Endpoint response body before transformations: {"statusCode": 500, "headers": {"Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8", "Content-Length": "290"}

I can't figure out how to get the data in the format in "urllib3" that will be accepted like it is with "requests". Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try without `.encode('utf-8')`?

Comment: I have that a try and still no luck. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

If you post your json as `data` in `requests` it will be submited like a html form:

```
"Content-Type":["application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]
```

If you want it to go as `json`, you should use

```
requests.post("https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/log-entries", json={'logbookTimestamp': timestamp, 'Name': "Fred"})
```

which submits data as:

```
"Content-Type":["application/json"]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However, I am fine with the way "requests" is working. I am looking for help with getting the same results from "urllib3". Regards,